# Unable to reuse polyOptions for new polygon

Tags: javascript, object, google-maps-api-3, scope

I'm working with the Google Maps v3 API, placing some polygons on the map. I create a 'polyOptions' object which is used when creating the polygon.

This only works once. For all other polygons, I have to create another identical 'polyOptions' object. Which is fine, but a bit repetitive, and this webpage is big enough already without repeating myself.

Have I misunderstood the nature of this JS object?

```
//Create array for polygons 

var polygons = [];

//first polygon

var myCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(55.81362907119961, -2.054443359375) //long list of coordinates
var polyOptions = {
    path: myCoordinates,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: "white",
    fillOpacity: 0.6
}
var poly1= new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
poly1.setMap(map);
polygons.push(poly1);

//second polygon

var myCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(54.94607621987403, -3.16131591796875) // long list of coordinates
var poly2 = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions); // doesn't work
poly2.setMap(map);
polygons.push(poly2);
```

Comment: You are assigning a new value to the variable `myCoordinates`. Why do you think it would in any way have an effect on the value of the `polyOptions.path` property?

Comment: Obviously, if I had realized that then I wouldn't have needed to ask the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must update the `path` property of your polyOptions at every step. At the moment your second polygon is drawn on the first with same coordinates.

```
// second polygon

// your var myCoordinates is already defined above, now use it by its name
myCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(54.94607621987403, -3.16131591796875) // long list of coordinates
polyOptions.path = myCoordinates; // here you set path to the new value
var poly2 = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions); // should work
poly2.setMap(map);
polygons.push(poly2);
```

Comment: Indeed it did work. An obvious mistake in hindsight!